# Grails: Tomcat won't shut down cleanly in prod

Tags: tomcat, deployment, grails, quartz-scheduler

I have an issue with shutting down a Grails app in production.

It shuts down cleanly when running from IntelliJ.  But on a standalone Tomcat 7, shutting down gets it into a zombie state where the java process still exists but HTTP requests hang.  I have to kill the java process (using kill).

I'm using Tomcat's standard bin/startup.sh and shutdown.sh.  With Tomcat stopped, I drop the .war into Tomcat's /webapps directory and then start.

I suspect it could be the Quartz job scheduler plugin, but I deployed a version with no jobs in grails-app/jobs and it still hangs.

Anybody run across this before?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Non-Daemon Threads

Probably one or more **non-daemon thread** is still running and preventing tomcat from a successful shutdown.

- open Terminal and type `ps -ef| grep java` and find your Tomcat7 **p_id**
- type `kill -3 p_id`
- type (in your Tomcat directory) `tail -200 logs/catalina.out`
- inspect **thread dump** generated by the `kill -3`
- look for non-daemon threads
- inspect your code to determine why that process is still alive.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!  Looks like another Grails plugin is starting OSGI and not shutting it down.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Kerem Baydoğan. There's likely a non-daemon thread which doesn't want to stop. A thread dump is a great way to track this down.

I would recommend connecting to your remote JVM using VisualVM. This has been an invaluable tool for me to gather information about my running applications. If you're on a Mac, it's installed as part of the OS already. From a terminal, just type 'jvisualvm'. If not on a Mac, it's a free download from http://visualvm.java.net/

Once installed, you may need to add a few JVM args to allow the remote connection. http://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html

Screenshot:
[image: Visual VM Thread Dump]

Comment: If you are not on Mac, you don't need to download VisualVM from visualvm.java.net. Java VisualVM is part of JDK 6 from JDK 6 update 7. Just go to jdk/bin directory and run jvisualvm or jvisualvm.exe.

Comment: Thanks, Derek.  VisualVM's cool!  But a warning to others: I set the JMX properties Derek references as JAVA_OPTS and got the following error trying to shut down Tomcat: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 3333.  To fix it, I had to set up the the JMX properties as CATALINA_OPTS and *not* JAVA_OPTS.

Comment: VisualVM is bundled with the Mac Os X SDK, no needs to download it.