# Tomcat shutdown VERY slow after calling shutdown.sh?

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat, tomcat6

My situation is like this:

Everytime before uploading war file to web-app folder, I stop Tomcat by calling `sh shutdown.sh`. It used to take about 30 seconds for a total shutdown. But now it doesn't work well anymore.

Actually, it did some work, because when I access the application from web-page it throws 503 error (Under Maintenance). But when I use `ps aux | grep tomcat` to check, the tomcat process is still there. And it will be there for around 5 - 10 mins.

I understand that it may need to take extra times to complete all the tasks, but it is way too slow (5 - 10 minutes), before it is stop totally. I don't understand why this happens, but there must be some reason. Maybe there's something to do with the code, or the new script of deployment we used recently. I just have almost no clue about where to check.

This is important to our team because we are using "auto-deployment", in which we use a script to auto-package war file, uploading and deploy on a specific time. If we started a new tomcat instance before the old one successfully shutdown, it will hang there for eternal, and cleaning up task by "kill -9" is daunting.

Is there anyone who has experimented this issue? Any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Q: So what's the last thing in the log when it's taking this 5-10 minutes?  ALSO: does "ps -eaf" give you any clues (or do you just see a Java process with zero CPU utilization)?  What's your Tomcat version?  Your OS?  ALSO: if you identify a "java" process "hanging" in "ps", you should get a stack trace: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_obtain_a_thread_dump_of_my_running_webapp_.3F

Comment: @paulsm4: Looking at the log, I see that even after calling shutdown.sh, my Quartz jobs still run. After a while an error get thrown out: SEVERE: The web application [/project] appears to have started a thread named [Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Comment: @paulsm4: by the way, I have the quartz job run about 10 seconds a time. Can this be an issue?

Comment: Take a look at the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554647/grails-tomcat-wont-shut-down-cleanly-in-prod Tomcat will wait for all non-daemon threads to finish before closing. The answer in the link will tell you how to determine what is still running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hoàng Long -

Thank you for the update.

1)  The fact that you see your Quartz jobs running, and the error message, are both significant:

> SEVERE: The web application [/project] appears to have started a
>   thread named [Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()] but has
>   failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

2) One suggestion is configuration:

> http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?17833-Spring-Quartz-Tomcat-no-shutdown
>
> I had the same problem. I fixed it by adding
>   `destroy-method="destroy"` to the SchedulerFactoryBean definition.
>   This way spring closes down the scheduler when the application is
>   stopped.

3) Another suggestion is to add a shutdown listener:

> http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/15/4341.page
>
> Using a context listener and introducing a timeout on shutdown solves
>   the issue for me. I just wait a second after shutting down:
>
> ```
>   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
>     try {
>       factory.getScheduler().shutdown();
>       Thread.sleep(1000);
> ```

Comment: I think I have figured out: the main reason is that I still have the transaction quartz jobs running. About the 3rd method of your answer, do you mean I must override Spring "ContextLoaderListener" for this task?

Answer (score 2):

If this is something that mystically started to happen within the last few days, perhaps you're running into the Linux leap second bug? For more information, see

https://serverfault.com/questions/403732/anyone-else-experiencing-high-rates-of-linux-server-crashes-during-a-leap-second

https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/articles/15145

http://pedroalves-bi.blogspot.fi/2012/07/java-leap-second-bug-how-to-fix-your.html